# F#: [<StructuredFormatDisplay>] vs override __.ToString(). ¿What it's wrong?

Tags: f#, attributes, record, tostring

Context: 
Running F# in a containerized environment with `dotnet 2.2.203`
on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop machine

Question: The `StructuredFormatDisplay` in a Composed Record doesn't work.
Was it wrong?
These is the code

```
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{SizeGb}GB")>]
type Disk = 
    { SizeGb : int }
    override __.ToString() = sprintf "<%dGB>" __.SizeGb

[<StructuredFormatDisplay("Computer #{Id}: {Manufacturer}/{DiskCount}:{Disks}")>]
type Computer =
    { Id: int
      mutable Manufacturer: string
      mutable Disks: Disk list }
      override __.ToString() = sprintf "#%d<%s>%O" __.Id __.Manufacturer __.Disks


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let myPc =
        { Id = 0
          Manufacturer = "Computers Inc."
          Disks =
            [ { SizeGb = 100 }
              { SizeGb = 250 }
              { SizeGb = 500 } ] }

    printfn "%%O = %O" myPc 
    printfn "%%A = %A" myPc   
    0
```

And the output

```
%O = #0<Computers Inc.>[<100GB>; <250GB>; <500GB>]
%A = Computer #0: Computers Inc./3:[...GB; ...GB; ...GB]
```

The %A pattern for the Disk record in Computer record just print some ... dots!

But %O is well printed.

Comment: See [bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/6753). Work around mentioned there is to increase the print depth with `fsi.PrintDepth <- 10000`.

Comment: It looks like fsi.PrintDepth is only available in .fsx files. Is there a way to edit the print depth in regular .fs files?

Answer (score 3):

I confirm that this issue also happens in my context too.

When you print %A directly on a disk list, output is okay:

```
printfn "%A" [{SizeGb = 10}] // output: [10GB]
```

But when the disk list is printed indirectly as in your code:

```
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("Computer #{Id}: {Manufacturer}/{DiskCount}:{Disks}")>]
```

We receive dots.

I think this is a bug of the F# core library. One workaround could be adding a new string property holding the formatted string of the disk list, and use that property instead:

```
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("Computer #{Id}: {Manufacturer}/{DiskCount}:{DisksStr}")>]
type Computer =
{ Id: int
  mutable Manufacturer: string
  mutable Disks: Disk list }
  member this.DisksStr = sprintf "%A" this.Disks
```

Comment: Thanks @Nghia, Your code is a nice workaround, but a workaround at the end. If It is a real bug on core library we have to raise an issue. Wait to confirm this with other answers.